# Array from php to jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

PHP:

```
json_encode($data)
```

outputs

> [{"sid":"0032","name":"Germany"}]

I want to consume this in jquery-ui autocomplete. But in jquery-ui doc the source looks like this

```
    var projects = [
        {
            value: "jquery",
            label: "jQuery",
            desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
            icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
        }
    ];
```

How can I convert the php output to such an array in javascript?

reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remake the array:

```
$toJSON = array();
foreach($data as $num => $val){
    $toJSON[$num]['value'] = $val['sid'];
    $toJSON[$num]['label'] = $val['name'];
}
echo json_encode($toJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var availableTags = <?=json_encode($yourArray);?>;

$( "#yourInput_text" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#yourInput_text").val(ui.item.name);
        return false;                                               },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#yourInput_text").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#yourInput).val(ui.item.sid);                                                                
        return false;                                               },
minLength: 4                                                            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`var projects = eval(data);`

in your javascript code.

Comment: there is no need to use eval there, with php you can put the json encoded array wherever you want